# How to check if all checkboxes are unchecked? AHK

Tags: checkbox, autohotkey

I need to check if all checkboxes are not selected, if all is unchecked do something.

I managed to do it using the `if` statement for all variables but I need a better solution instead of using the name of all variables because I pretend to add many more.

Thanks

```
#!s::
Gui, Destroy
gui, font, S12  ;Change font size to 12
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x0 w460 h180, Pesquisa: ;add a groupbox 
; gui, Add, Checkbox, x20 y30 checked1 vahk, AutoHotkey.com ;first checkbox and move down / over a bit
gui, Add, Checkbox, x20 y30 checked0 vstackBR, Pt.StackOverflow.com ;first checkbox and move down / over a bit
;gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vstackBR, Pt.StackOverflow.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked1 vstack, StackOverflow.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked1 vstackAHK, StackOverflow.com/AutoHotkey
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vahk, AutoHotkey.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vReddit,Reddit.com
Gui, Add, Checkbox, Checked0 Vtech,Techonthenet.Com
gui, Add, Text, x10 y+20, Pesquisar por:
gui, Add, Edit ,x+10 yp-5 w360  vSearchTerm 
gui, Add, Button, w82 gSearch Default, &Pesquisar

gui, Show 
GuiControl,Focus,SearchTerm
return

Search:
Gui Submit ; Needed to pull inf0 from controls

; if all checkboxes are not selected
if (stackBR=0 AND stackAHK=0 AND ahk=0 AND Reddit=0 AND tech=0)
    run "http://www.google.com/search?q=%SearchTerm%"

If stack 
    run "http://www.google.com/search?q=%SearchTerm%+site:stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option, which is also probably the easiest to understand, would be to keep track of the checkboxes' checked states by calling some function every time their state is changed.
This can be done easily with a `g-label`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#label)</sup>.
So you could do something like this:

```
gui, font, S12  ;Change font size to 12
Gui, Add, GroupBox, x0 w460 h180, Pesquisa: ;add a groupbox 
; gui, Add, Checkbox, x20 y30 checked1 vahk, AutoHotkey.com ;first checkbox and move down / over a bit
gui, Add, Checkbox, x20 y30 checked0 vstackBR gUpdateState, Pt.StackOverflow.com ;first checkbox and move down / over a bit
;gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vstackBR, Pt.StackOverflow.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked1 vstack gUpdateState, StackOverflow.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked1 vstackAHK gUpdateState, StackOverflow.com/AutoHotkey
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vahk gUpdateState, AutoHotkey.com
gui, Add, Checkbox, checked0 vReddit gUpdateState,Reddit.com
Gui, Add, Checkbox, Checked0 Vtech gUpdateState,Techonthenet.Com
gui, Add, Text, x10 y+20, Pesquisar por:
gui, Add, Edit ,x+10 yp-5 w360  vSearchTerm 
gui, Add, Button, w82 gSearch Default, &Pesquisar

CheckboxValues := 2

gui, Show 
GuiControl,Focus,SearchTerm
return

Search:
Gui Submit ; Needed to pull inf0 from controls

; if all checkboxes are not selected
if (stackBR=0 AND stackAHK=0 AND ahk=0 AND Reddit=0 AND tech=0)
    run "http://www.google.com/search?q=%SearchTerm%"

If stack 
    run "http://www.google.com/search?q=%SearchTerm%+site:stackoverflow.com"
return

F1::
    if (!CheckboxValues)
        MsgBox, % "All checkboxes unchecked!"
    else
        MsgBox, % CheckboxValues " checkboxes still checked!"
return

UpdateState()
{
    global CheckboxValues ;use a variable outside of this function's scope
    GuiControlGet, value, , % A_GuiControl
    CheckboxValues += value ? 1 : -1
}
```

This is a very basic implementation where `1` is added, or subtracted, from the global variable `CheckboxValues` when a checkbox is checked or unchecked <sub><sup>(state is retrieved with `GuiControlGet`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControlGet.htm)</sup>)</sup></sub>.
If `CheckboxValues` is zero, then they're all unchecked.
You just have to initialize the variable with the amount of checkboxes that are checked in the beginning `CheckboxValues := 2`.

In this example code you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to display a messagebox of the current state at any point.

Of course you could implement way more advanced ways to keep track of the checked states, but I think here it's enough that I show a basic, but well functioning way of doing it.
You can look into more advanced solutions if you so wish.